# Error in Custom Deserialization of String Vec from JSON with Serde in Rust

Tags: json, string, rust, deserialization, serde

I am trying to deserialize:

```json
"comments": ["string"]

//And

"comments": "string"
```

To :

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct Block {
    pub comments: Comments,
}
```

With :

```rust
pub fn deserialize_vec<'de, D, T>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<T>, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    T: serde::Deserialize<'de>,
{
    let s:T = serde::Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?; // how to peek_char
    Ok(vec![s])
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2ecd6d75f8785b4f4cf154ee9cbd3e35)

Note that this is the minimal version, I need these attributes for many other types.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be886f3e23a33d0aca4710c1135ba841

Comment: Hi Mohit, I remember seeing this as an example directly in serde documentation, also there is a crate. https://docs.rs/serde_single_or_vec/latest/serde_single_or_vec/

Comment: *"Error in Custom Deserialization"* - please actually post the error here, so far there is only code.

Comment: _Finomnis_ , the error was in conditional deserialization of variants... Error("invalid type: sequence, expected a string")

Answer (score 0):

As *Stargateur* suggested in the comment,
I came up with something like this...

```rust
pub fn deserialize_vec<'de, D, T>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<T>, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    T: serde::Deserialize<'de>,
{
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    #[serde(untagged)]
    enum VecOrType<T> {
        Vec(Vec<T>),
        Type(T),
    }

    let value:VecOrType<T> = serde::Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    match value {
        VecOrType::Vec(vec) => {
            Ok(vec)
        },
        VecOrType::Type(typ) => {
            Ok(vec!(typ))
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=05040ac67cf1fcf0cd6ee6317b721c74)

Thanks *Stargateur* and *Ahmed Masud*